# mysqlslap number in sql statement to change with iteration

Tags: mysql, benchmark

I am trying to figure out how to increment a number in a `mysqlslap` query with every iteratiom.

Let me explain what I exactly mean:

I got a query:

```
SELECT age FROM member WHERE id = [some number]
```

is there a way to write `mysqlslap` parameter, so it iterates the [some number] while executing the query multiple time ? I do not want to keep doing the same query, as it caches.

I went through the documentation on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqlslap.html
but did not really find the straight answer to my question.

If there is not `mysqlslap` solution, maybe there is a way to achieve this with some other tool.

Cheers for help !

Comment: when you say " I do not want to keep doing the same query, as it caches.", are you just concerned with the performance disregarding the query cache?

Answer (score 1):

If you are worried about the performance effect of caching the result in the query cache, you can disable caching in your query by using [`SQL_NO_CACHE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//query-cache-in-select.html):

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE age FROM member WHERE id = [some number]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would consider the random function.

For instance:

```
select age 
from member 
where id = FLOOR(RAND()*10000))
```

In this example, 10000 is the maximum id value present in the table.